# Tool Tip to show entire GridView row

Tags: c#, asp.net, tooltip

I want to create a tooltip feature that will display all of a user data that is being displayed in a gridview.

Expected Result: A GridView displays Last_Name,First_Name,Telephone,Cell_Phone. I want a tool tip to display with a mousehover over that users row of information and display all of the data in that tooltip. The data is only generated when a users uses my search box feature so it can't be a static tooltip string. I"m using a sqldatasource to fill in the gridview which i'm not sure how to call. The only thing I can find is by making the gridview a label which I don't want to do. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView2" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" CellPadding="4" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" GridLines="None" HorizontalAlign="Center" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" ForeColor="#333333">
    <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="#284775" />
    <Columns>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Last_Name" HeaderText="Last_Name" SortExpression="Last_Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="First_Name" HeaderText="First_Name" SortExpression="First_Name" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Middle_Int" HeaderText="Middle_Int" SortExpression="Middle_Int" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Telephone" HeaderText="Work Telephone" SortExpression="Telephone" />
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Cell_Phone" HeaderText="Work Cell" SortExpression="Cell_Phone" />
    </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

SQLDataSource Connection:

```
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myconnection %>" SelectCommand="SELECT [Last_Name], [First_Name], [Middle_Int], [Rank], [Telephone], [Cell_Phone], [Unit], [UserName]  FROM [Person_Search] WHERE (([Middle_Int] LIKE '%' + @Middle_Int + '%') OR ([Cell_Phone] LIKE '%' + @Cell_Phone + '%')  OR ([First_Name] LIKE '%' + @First_Name + '%')  OR ([Telephone] LIKE '%' + @Telephone + '%') OR ([Unit] = @Unit) OR ([Last_Name] LIKE '%' + @Last_Name + '%') OR ([UserName] LIKE '%' + @UserName + '%'))">
    <SelectParameters>
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Middle_Int" PropertyName="Text" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Cell_Phone" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="First_Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Telephone" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="TextBox1" Name="Last_Name" PropertyName="Text" Type="String" />
    </SelectParameters>
</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

Label Control View Code:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Logid">
<ItemTemplate>
     <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("cityid") %>' ToolTip='<%# Bind("cityName") %>' ></asp:Label>
 </ItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the RowDataBound event to add the ToolTip property to a GridViewRow.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is d datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        StringBuilder tooltip = new StringBuilder();

        //add the data to the tooltip stringbuilder
        tooltip.Append(row["Last_Name"] + ", ");
        tooltip.Append(row["First_Name"] + ", ");
        tooltip.Append(row["Middle_Int"] + ", ");
        tooltip.Append(row["Telephone"] + ", ");
        tooltip.Append(row["Cell_Phone"]);

        //add the tooltip attribute to the row
        e.Row.Attributes.Add("ToolTip", tooltip.ToString());
    }
}
```